# right margin does not work

Tags: margins

with this code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a3paper,
 total={297mm,420mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=10mm,
 %right=20mm
% bmargin=20mm
 }
 
\begin{document}
%\section{Some dummy text}
%\blindtext[10]
%\lipsum[2-14]
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\textwidth}>{\centering}p{0.3\textwidth}>{\centering}p{0.3\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.3\textwidth}}
\hline
%\multirow{2}{*}{Country}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Population}&\multirow{2}{*}{Change (\%)}\\\cline{2-3}
&2016&2017&\\
\hline
%China&1,403,500,365&1,409,517,397&+0.4\%\\
testo1 testo1 testo1testo1 testo1 testo1testo1 testo1 testo1testo1 testo1 testo1 

&
testo2 testo2 testo2testo2 testo2 testo2testo2 testo2 testo2testo2 testo2 testo2  

&
testo3 testo3 testo3testo3 testo3 testo3 testo3 testo3 testo3testo3 testo3 testo3&+0.4\%\\

testo1 testo1 testo1testo1 testo1 testo1testo1 testo1 testo1testo1 testo1 testo1 

&
testo2 testo2 testo2testo2 testo2 testo2testo2 testo2 testo2testo2 testo2 testo2  

&
testo3 testo3 testo3testo3 testo3 testo3 testo3 testo3 testo3testo3 testo3 testo3&+0.4\%\\

%\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I would have an A3 page with 20mm margin on top, bottom, left and right, but it produces just left and top margin, not left and bottom margin.
why?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Note that your geometry options gives a warning in the log. ANd why both a3paper and total? Are you trying to do a3paper landscape?

Comment: no, I need A3 portrait with 3 column and 5 horizontal line. Then I will put inside text in each cell

Comment: Please note: 4 * (0.3\textwidth + 2\tabcolsep) = 1.2 \textwidth + 8 \tabcolsep > 1 \textwidth and don't forget \parindent.

Comment: If I remove `total` and adjusts as cabohah suggests I get an a3paper with left margin = 20mm, top = 10mm. I'd probably use `margin=20mm` instead to set all at once.

Comment: @daleif: sorry I do not understand.can you made me an example?

Comment: Give a3paper to the class, and just use `\geometry[margon=20mm]{geometry}` that gives you an a3 with 20mm margin all the way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `tabularx` (or `xltabular` if page breaks are needed). For better lines, I also suggest to use `booktabs`. And IMHO it does not make sense, to make the last column have a quarter of the page width, if there are only small percentage values in it. For the paper size A3 it is enough to load `geometry` with option `a3paper`. And to set all margins to 2cm option `margin=2cm` would be a good idea. If you don't want to use page header and footer, also options `nohead` and `nofoot` or `noheadfoot` can be added, depending on the expected result.

So I would suggest, for example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a3paper,margin=2cm,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
 
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright}X>{\centering}X>{\raggedleft}Xr}
\toprule
&2016&\centering 2017&\\
\toprule
testo1 testo1 testo1testo1 testo1 testo1testo1 testo1 testo1testo1 testo1
testo1
& testo2 testo2 testo2testo2 testo2 testo2testo2 testo2 testo2testo2 testo2
  testo2  
& testo3 testo3 testo3testo3 testo3 testo3 testo3 testo3 testo3testo3 testo3
testo 3
&+0.4\%\\
testo1 testo1 testo1testo1 testo1 testo1testo1 testo1 testo1testo1 testo1
testo1 
& testo2 testo2 testo2testo2 testo2 testo2testo2 testo2 testo2testo2 testo2
  testo2   
& testo3 testo3 testo3testo3 testo3 testo3 testo3 testo3 testo3testo3 testo3
testo3
&+0.4\%\\
\blindtext[1] & \blindtext[2] & \blindtext[3] &+0.4\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]